# How to deserialize derived class with other derived class as property

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance, deserialization, abstract

I have 2 projects. One is a WPF application and second is my "toolkit" with predefined WPF control, XML deserialization and some base configuration classes.

In my toolkit I have a `ConfigurationBase` class:

```
public class ConfigurationBase : XmlDeserializeConfigSectionHandler
{
      public GuiConfigurationBase GuiConfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

This is `GuiConfigurationBase`

```
public class GuiConfigurationBase
{
    public int LogLineCount { get; set; }
}
```

My toolkit contains predefined View for in app log messages. So my `LogViewModel` constructor requires a `ConfigurationBase` which should contain `GuiConfiguration` with `LogLineCount` property.

This is because I don't want to implement in app log for every application.

Then I have a WPF project. It contains a class `Config` which is derived from `ConfigurationBase`. It's extended with some other props which are not important.

I also needed to extend `GuiConfigurationBase` so I have class called `GuiConfiguration` which derives from `GuiConfigurationBase`.

```
public class Config : ConfigurationBase
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }
}

public class GuiConfiguration : GuiConfigurationBase
{
    public int TextSize { get; set; }
}
```

I am also using XmlSerializer for deseserializing my XML file. I need to fill both of my derived classes.

How I can achieve this please?

I tried some abstraction for base classes but with no success.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Typo alert: it's spelled **to derive / derived** - not "to derrive / derrived" - one "r" is QUITE enough

Comment: as long as the referenced classes are all serializable you should be able to deserialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. 
It's necessary to use `XmlAttributeOverrides`.

Because I have two projects I had to use reflection to retrieve classes which derive from `GuiConfigurationBase`. (I don't know anything about project where is my toolkit project referenced)

Then add new `XmlElementAttribute` for each class (in my case it should be enough to use Linq `First()` method) - This should be same as `XmlIncludeAttribute`(Type)

And finaly add `XmlAttributeOverrides` for `ConfigurationBase` class's property `GuiConfiguration`

Here is my deserialize method:

```
 public T Deserialize<T>(string input) where T : class
    {
        //Init attrbibutee overrides
        XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

        //Load all types which derive from GuiConfiguration base
        var guiConfTypes = (from lAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                            from lType in lAssembly.GetTypes()
                            where typeof(GuiConfigurationBase).IsAssignableFrom(lType) && lType != typeof(GuiConfigurationBase)
                            select lType).ToArray();


        //All classes which derive from GuiConfigurationBase
        foreach (var guiConf in guiConfTypes)
        {
            XmlElementAttribute attr = new XmlElementAttribute
            {
                ElementName = guiConf.Name,
                Type = guiConf
            };

            attrs.XmlElements.Add(attr);
        }

        //Add Attribute overrides for ConfigurationBase class's property GuiConfiguration
        attrOverrides.Add(typeof(ConfigurationBase), nameof(ConfigurationBase.GuiConfiguration), attrs);

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), attrOverrides);

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
        {
            return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }
```

I hope it will help someone else :-)